# iOS: google admob banner does not fit inside 320x50 GADBannerView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode6

I have followed the getting started tutorial for displaying admob banners in my storyboard project (https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start?hl=en). I have it working as expected in one view but I have another view that is causing me trouble.

On my second view, the GADBannerView is setup with constraint of 50 height and 320 width and is centered horizontally. When the view loads it starts an adreqeust for my iOS emulator like so:

```
NSLog(@"Google Mobile Ads SDK version: %@", [GADRequest sdkVersion]);
GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];
request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];

self.googleBanner.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-xxxxx/xxxxx";
self.googleBanner.rootViewController = self;
[self.googleBanner loadRequest:request];
```

The ad loads just fine but in order to see it I have to scroll it into view. Its as if the size of the view is 100 height and the top position of the google ad is at 50. Since the first view I created loads the ad into the correct position and the second view does not I started to check what differences there might be. I couldn't find any differences.

I deleted the GADBannerView out of the second view and followed the same instructions again from the getting started guide but still have to scroll the ad into view to see it. Yet the first view remains fine.

Are there common mistakes that I could making that I may not be aware of? I relatively new to iOS development and objective-c in general but any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

edit:
image of storyboard view: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIFxG.png

Comment: could you provide a screenshot with your view(s) and constraints?

Comment: added screenshot. posted to http://postimg.org/image/oh6rt2tph/

Comment: pls add screenshot of interface builder scene (where you set up your views and constraints) and if possible - provide there a chunk of code with adding self.googleBanner to parent view (or whole class)

Comment: posted to http://i.imgur.com/0v6zDAN.png. hope this is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because your screen was larger then 320 and banner trying to adopt to it. Try to set banner size manually:

```
self.googleBanner.adSize = kGADAdSizeBanner
```